# How to place 2 figures on top and 1 figure on the corner?

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have three images with the same size and I want to group them together as they're talking about the same subject.

1. It would be best if I can put them in one row but I couldn't as they're quite small that way.
   [image]
2. If I put two images on the first row and one in the middle of the second row then zoom is good but there are some waste spaces which I want to remove as in the `1` in the figure below.
3. How can I group 3 images togethers but put one in the corner like `2` so we can use more space?

Is it weird to do it like that? 
I think it is also okay if we can force to put 3 figures like that but use 3 separate figure labels instead of (a), (b), (c).

Also please suggest if you have a better idea to show 3 figures like this.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[]{subfig}
    \usepackage{stfloats}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    
    \begin{document}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{a}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{b}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\par 
    \subfloat[legend]{\label{c}\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{my fig}
    \label{fig}
    \end{figure*}
    \end{document}
```

From the comment, I tried to use minipage but the text is superimposed on the figure. The layout is probably the best one but I searched and didn't see any similar problem like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!t]

\centering

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: May a minipage environment do the job ?

Comment: @Piroooh how would you set position with minipage?

Comment: I just realized that minipage just place the images automatically from left to right, top to bottom so I just need to create 3 minipages and adjust the widths so two fit on the top and one on the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking the situation: Just place the three images in a single column, set the images' widths to `\linewidth`, and spare yourself pointless formatting hassles.

If you don't want to allow the pair of text lines below the `figure` in the right-hand column, just replace both instances of `\par` in the `figure` environment with `\par\bigskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[Legend A]{\label{a}\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\par
\subfloat[Legend B]{\label{b}\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\par 
\subfloat[Legend C]{\label{c}\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
\caption{my fig}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works as well. I created minipage but the text was superimposed on the figures.

Comment: One problem with this is that the figure is placed too far from the reference point. This is probably because it's hard to find a vertical column like that.

Comment: @emnha - You wrote, "One problem with this is that the figure is placed too far from the reference point". The best remedy to this problem is generally to place the `figure` material three or four paragraphs earlier in the document.

Comment: I put it in the beginning of the section but somehow it skips one page and place it on the next page while there is place on the page near the reference point. Not sure if this is particular for my code only.

Comment: @emnha - Is something stopping you from placing the `figure` material 2 or 3 paragraphs *before* the `\section` command?

Comment: It is supposed to put in Section V but it doesn't place properly even I put it in the Section I. I have tried to put it in many places from Section I to V but couldn't make it work.

Comment: @emnha - I have exactly zero information about the details of your document setup, other than that you employ the `IEEEtran` document class in two-column mode and that the document contains (at least) 5 sections. I can therefore only suggest that you either go back to placing the three subfigures in a single row, or create three separate `figure` environments with one graphic each, and trust that LaTeX will have more success placing smaller `\figure` floats in a way that meets your formatting needs.

Comment: Yeah, I did 3 separate figures at first and then I wanted to make sure that they're always grouped together so it is easier to check them. Do you have any sharing about minipage that I updated in my post?

Comment: @emnha - One additional thought: Are you maybe writing `\begin{figure}[ht]` instead of `\begin{figure}[!ht]`, i.e., are you leaving off the `!` symbol. If so, that would definitely explain your lack of success in getting the float to show up where you'd like it to.

Comment: nope, I replaced `!ht` with `!t` if that matters.

Comment: You also might try [!tp] in case the figure is larger than `\textheight-2\floatsep`.

Comment: I tried reduce to `0.8\linewidth` and it works now. I still like the layout as minipage better though.

Comment: Something strange with my images as if I make it larger than `0.8\linewidth` then it would move to further away.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but not on the first (or current) page.  Admittedly, subfigures would have been tricky without `\ContinuedFloat`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{minipage}\hfill% or \hspace{\columnsep}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{legend}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```